# Need help detecting collision in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I’ve tried multiple things to try to detect collision between the player turtle and the apple turtle and nothing happens. What I wanted it to do is that when the turtles get too close, the player turtle disappears. If the apple gets to low below the player, it resets back up top.
Here is the code I’ve done. I’m new to code so I’m not very good.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

ground_height = -200
# lists for the turtle to use
colors = ["blue", "darkorange", "cyan", "green", "black"]
shapes = [ "triangle", "turtle", "classic"]
sizes = [0.5,1,1.25,1.5,2]
#creates the turtles
player = trtl.Turtle(shape = rand.choice(shapes)) #gives  the circle its shape
player.turtlesize(1.5)
counter = trtl.Turtle()
apple = trtl.Turtle(shape = "circle")
apple.color("red")
apple.turtlesize(rand.choice(sizes))
#gives turtles their colors 
player.color(rand.choice(colors))
player.penup()
apple.penup()
apple.setx(rand.randint(0,200))
apple.sety(rand.randint(0,200))
#sets up timer
font_setup = ("Arial", 20, "normal")
timer = 0
counter_interval = 1000
timer_up = False
counter.hideturtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-200,160)
#gives player movement
def move_player():
  player.forward(10)

def player_left():
  player.left(180)

def player_right():
    player.right(180)

apple.right(90)

#lets the timer start and end
def countdown():
  global timer, timer_up
  counter.clear()
  if timer <= -1:
    counter.write("Time's Up", font=font_setup)
    timer_up = True
  else:
    counter.write("Timer: " + str(timer), font=font_setup)
    timer += 1
    apple.forward(10)
    counter.getscreen().ontimer(countdown,     counter_interval)
countdown()
    # lets the player move on key press
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(move_player, "w")
wn.onkeypress(player_left,"a")
wn.onkeypress(player_right,"d")
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: How does the posted code compare to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Testing for collision can be as simple as adding a clause to the `if` statement in the `countdown()` function:

```
elif apple.distance(player) < 15:
    counter.write("Collision!", font=FONT)
```

Below is my rework of your code that incorporates this change as well addresses various style and coding issues I noticed:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint

# lists for the turtle to use
COLORS = ['blue', 'dark orange', 'cyan', 'green', 'black']
SHAPES = ['triangle', 'turtle', 'classic']
SIZES = [0.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2]

FONT = ('Arial', 20, 'normal')

COUNTER_INTERVAL = 1000

# give player movement

def move_player():
    player.forward(10)

def player_left():
    player.left(180)

def player_right():
    player.right(180)

# set up timer
timer = 0

def countdown():
    global timer

    counter.clear()

    if timer <= -1:
        counter.write("Time's Up", font=FONT)
    elif apple.distance(player) < 15:
        counter.write("Collision!", font=FONT)
    else:
        counter.write("Timer: " + str(timer), font=FONT)
        timer += 1
        apple.forward(10)

        screen.ontimer(countdown, COUNTER_INTERVAL)

# create turtles
player = Turtle(shape=choice(SHAPES))
player.turtlesize(1.5)
player.color(choice(COLORS))
player.penup()

counter = Turtle()
counter.hideturtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-200, 160)

apple = Turtle(shape='circle')
apple.color('red')
apple.turtlesize(choice(SIZES))

apple.penup()
apple.setposition(randint(0, 200), randint(0, 200))
apple.setheading(270)

screen = Screen()

# let player move on key press
screen.onkeypress(move_player, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(player_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(player_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

countdown()

screen.mainloop()
```

> What I wanted it to do is that when the turtles get too close, the
> player turtle disappears. If the apple gets to low below the player,
> it resets back up top

My fix above just detects and announces the collision, you'll need to augment it to include these additional actions.